# Passing Dynamic Color hex value to data-pb-tint-colour for PaintJS Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple color picker script here that uses the jquery hex color picker. I want to pass the hex value from the color picker to the data-tint-pb-colour value in the paintbrushjs plugin. I have spent the last day trying to make this work and the value won't pass for some reason.

## HTML

```
 <head>

   <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-hex-colorpicker.js"></script>    
   <script src="common.js"></script>
   <script src="paintbrush.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>



        <input type="text" id="color-picker1" placeholder="Click for Demo" />
        <img src="/images/Layer2.png" class="filter-tint" data-pb-tint-opacity="0.5" data-pb-tint-colour="#F69023" id="image">

    </body>
```

### Javascript/Jquery

```
<script>
$('#color-picker1').on('input', function() { 
    var color= $("#color-picker1").val();
    $("#color-picker1").val(color); 
    $('#image').attr('data-pb-tint-colour', color);  });

    jQuery("#color-picker1").hexColorPicker();
</script>
```

It's a rather simple html/jquery coding job I have here and it boggles me why it will not work.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sg02Lctb/)

### Update #1

I first noticed that the paintbrush.js plugin and common.js plugin were not being called so I thought this would fixed the issue. Once placing them in as script sources the tint worked but did not change when I picked a new color in the color picker.

Updated Fiddle.

#### Update #2

[Updated Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/sg02Lctb/3/) I forgot to include the css and the external js scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jQuery instead of $, if you have an inline jQuery.

```
<script>
function watchTextbox() {
    var color= jQuery("#color-picker1").val();
    jQuery('#image').attr('data-pb-tint-colour', color); 
}
setInterval(watchTextbox, 100);
jQuery("#color-picker1").hexColorPicker();
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated the code as you have suggested above and the color tint on the image is still not changing.

Comment: Made the update as shown above, No Still not working.

Comment: It only works, if you click inside the input box... then the event fires.

Comment: You should check now. The set interval seems to be the only thing that will work in your particular case

Comment: I honestly don't know what's going on. if this worked for you it's not working on my dev box on my end. I hate telling you that. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84304/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-webzy).

Comment: not working in my fiddle can you provide me a fiddle of your own with the working code?

Comment: Sorry, your Fiddle stopped working for some reason. I can't spend any more time on this. My last solution worked at the time your Fiddle still worked. Please, fix your Fiddle (whatever went "funny" with it) and then try to apply my solution to it - it will work.

Comment: No Problem, I've debugged the fiddle in the javascript console and it's throwing a Uncaught ReferenceError: addLoadEvent is not defined error.  So your code is working, it's just not applying to my image for some reason. I will figure it out thanks and I apologize.